# SQL Server query issues

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

We have a SQL Server 2012 database with our live project including multiple tables and records, Basically We are facing a problem with SQL queries on a table where two same SQL queries. The first SQL query is taking less execution time and second SQL query is getting tremendously slow to execute.

I don't know why it is happening someone could help me to solve this problem?
Our two queries are given below....

**First query** (taking so much time to execute):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 TrackerResponse.EventName,TrackerResponse.ReceiveTime,ISNull(TrackerResponse.InputStatus,0)  AS InputStatus,
                TrackerResponse.Latitude,TrackerResponse.Longitude,TrackerResponse.Speed,
                TrackerResponse.TrackerID,TrackerResponse.OdoMeter,TrackerResponse.Direction,
                UserCar.CarNo FROM TrackerResponse
                INNER JOIN UserCar ON (UserCar.TrackerID = TrackerResponse.TrackerID)
                WHERE  (TrackerResponse.EventName IS NOT NULL AND TrackerResponse.EventName<>'')
                AND TrackerResponse.TrackerID = 112 Order By ID DESC) AS Events)
```

Second query (taking less execution time):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 TrackerResponse.EventName,TrackerResponse.ReceiveTime,ISNull(TrackerResponse.InputStatus,0)  AS InputStatus,
                TrackerResponse.Latitude,TrackerResponse.Longitude,TrackerResponse.Speed,
                TrackerResponse.TrackerID,TrackerResponse.OdoMeter,TrackerResponse.Direction,
                UserCar.CarNo FROM TrackerResponse
                INNER JOIN UserCar ON (UserCar.TrackerID = TrackerResponse.TrackerID)
                WHERE  (TrackerResponse.EventName IS NOT NULL AND TrackerResponse.EventName<>'')
                AND TrackerResponse.TrackerID = 56 Order By ID DESC) AS Events
```

Comment: Check the execution plans for the two queries. Are you missing any indexes? How many rows match the criteria in each case? If `TrackerID=46` returns 100 times more rows than 112 and you don't have any indexes, the query can take 100 times more. Post the execution plans for both queries

Answer (score 0):

I see Both queries are similar with an exception of tracker id..so my best guess would be ,this query might be a victim of [Parameter sniffing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33698/parameter-sniffing-vs-variables-vs-recompile-vs-optimize-for-unknown)..

Try using Option(Recompile) like below to see if this is the cause and follow article referred in above link for resolution

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 TrackerResponse.EventName,TrackerResponse.ReceiveTime,ISNull(TrackerResponse.InputStatus,0)  AS InputStatus,
                TrackerResponse.Latitude,TrackerResponse.Longitude,TrackerResponse.Speed,
                TrackerResponse.TrackerID,TrackerResponse.OdoMeter,TrackerResponse.Direction,
                UserCar.CarNo FROM TrackerResponse
                INNER JOIN UserCar ON (UserCar.TrackerID = TrackerResponse.TrackerID)
                WHERE  (TrackerResponse.EventName IS NOT NULL AND TrackerResponse.EventName<>'')
                AND TrackerResponse.TrackerID = 56 Order By ID DESC
option(recompile) 
AS Events)
```

Comment: are you sure about it that all problem related to parameter sniffing..???

Comment: You can confirm that by looking at execution plans and checking for expected rows vs actual rows

Comment: Using Option(Recompile) with the query takes 6sec less than Previous Execution time

Comment: This can be a new question ,please post the query,execution plan,schema of tables involved and counts of each table

Comment: @Sahityakanral:I suggest you reading this ,before implementing Recompile option..http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options